# why is addition operation faster than multiplication operation?

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture, computation

Could someone please explain why is addition operation faster than multiplication operation ?

for example if we need to multiply 25 by 50

will the compiler transform it to a for loop of additions ?

Comment: You are looking for what is called "micro-code". This differs from architecture to architecture. If you find a manual on any of the recent AMD x64 ones let me know ASAP lol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiplication is a much more complex process, requiring more silicon either [as a multiplier circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_multiplier) or [in a lookup table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table) in order to reach the same level of performance as [provided by addition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_%28electronics%29).

Answer (score 0):

will the compiler transform it to a for loop of additions ?

> > No if the processor already has a multiply instruction, which most processors anyway have.